# ngSatellizer and Hapi/Bell not playing well together. Promise will not resolve for Twitter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, twitter, hapi.js

I've been looking into possible solutions for this problem everywhere and can't seem to come up with anything in particular. From modifying my callback to various other tinkering in Hapi, I cannot get the promise to resolve on the Angular side. Strangely enough, the Twitter popup window will not close. If I close it manually, then the promise is rejected.

So, I've had to configure this to work around a rejected promise and it's just nasty...

```
//Angular Method
$scope.addTwitter = function(){
    $auth.authenticate('twitter').then(function(res){
      // success
    }, function(res){
      // failure
    });
};




//Hapi Route
//Handles both POST and GET and will successfully authenticate for Twitter on /auth/twitter
var User = require('../../models/user');

module.exports = {
  description: 'Twitter oAuth for the front-end.',
  tags:['twitter'],
  auth: {
    strategies: ['twitter'],
    mode: 'try'
  },
  handler: function(request, reply){
    if (!request.auth.isAuthenticated){
        return reply('Authentication failed due to: ' + request.auth.error.message).code(400);
    }

    if(request.auth.isAuthenticated){
      User.addTwitter(request.state['hapi-cookie'].id, request.auth.credentials, function(err, results){
        //Twitter Object
        //console.log(request.auth.credentials)
        reply().code(200);
        //return reply.redirect('/#/thanks');
      });
    }
  }
};
```

I have tried many different things over the last few days to get this working correctly. Alas I am here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As far as I know, Bell doesn't work with Satellizer.

Comment: After struggling with it for quite some time, I found out the hard way, haha. I ended up dropping Satellizer and creating my own popups via the window object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone in the future...

I ended up creating popups with the window object and long polling for changes in the session to notify a successful/failed attempt. This is easiest to do if you are using Angular with Hapi.

Comment: I'm using Facebook as provider and I get the same issue. The promise is not resolved to the angular side. following the express way as showed in the example in the official repository, from the backend it returns the token but before something happens and I don''t know how to fix it.I don't want to create the popup window.